# If I'm in branch "Foo2" and do "git push origin Foo", what happens?

Tags: git

I had a branch - let's call it "Foo" - then I branched from Foo to create Foo2, Foo is now a legacy branch - my current work focuses on Foo2.

Now I'm afraid that I may forget I'm working on Foo2, and so I may do `git push origin Foo` (especially likely due to bash's tab-completion behavior). I'm worried that this may somehow push changes from Foo2 to Foo.

So, what will actually happen?

Comment: If your local `Foo` is updated against its remote, nothing will happen - as you're already up-to-date. The command `git push origin Foo` attempts to push changes from the local `Foo` branch to the remote `Foo` branch.

Comment: Meaning - no matter which branch you currently have checked out, you told it to push `Foo`, so it does. `Foo` will push to it's default, since you didn't specify to do otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Let's check [the documentation for `git push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push).  The general form of the command is `git push <repository> <src>:<dst>`, and we want to figure out what happens when `:<dst>` is omitted.

> If `git push [<repository>]` without any `<refspec>` argument is set to update some ref at the destination with `<src>` with `remote.<repository>.push` configuration variable, `:<dst>` part can be omitted—​such a push will update a ref that `<src>` normally updates without any `<refspec>` on the command line. Otherwise, missing `:<dst>` means to update the same ref as the `<src>`.

<sup>(I promise, I didn't copy this from the [git man page generator](https://git-man-page-generator.lokaltog.net/).)</sup>

So whatever it does is going to involve the exact `<src>` you provided, meaning that as long as you don't create any more commits in your local `Foo` branch, running `git push origin Foo` won't find anything to push, and the remote `Foo` branch will stay unchanged.

Comment: [git-man-page-generator](https://git-man-page-generator.lokaltog.net/) made my day.